# jsvc no encuentra la clase en el .jar

Tags: java

Tengo la clase MonitorDaemon la cual deseo volver un servicio mediante jsvc

```
package com.base.daemon;

import org.apache.commons.daemon.Daemon;
import org.apache.commons.daemon.DaemonContext;
import org.apache.commons.daemon.DaemonInitException;

public class MonitorDaemon implements Daemon {

    private Thread myThread;
    private boolean stopped = false;
    private boolean lastOneWasATick = false;

    @Override
    public void init(DaemonContext daemonContext) throws DaemonInitException, Exception {
        System.out.println("MonitorDaemon init...");

        String[] args = daemonContext.getArguments();

        myThread = new Thread() {
            private long lastTick = 0;

            @Override
            public synchronized void start() {
                MonitorDaemon.this.stopped = false;
                super.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!stopped) {
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if (now - lastTick >= 10000) {
                        System.out.println(!lastOneWasATick ? "tick" : "tock");
                        lastOneWasATick = !lastOneWasATick;
                        lastTick = now;
                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(15000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        //Logger.getLogger(JDaemon.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("MonitorDaemon start in a Thread...");
        myThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("MonitorDaemon stop...");
        stopped = true;
        try {
            myThread.join(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("MonitorDaemon destroy...");
        myThread = null;
    }
}
```

En la ruta /usr/local/monitorFEL/lib/ tengo el .jar de commons-daemon y en la ruta /usr/local/monitorFEL/ tengo el .jar de la clase arriba detallada.  Ahora cuando ejecuto

```
./jsvc -debug -cp /usr/local/monitorFEL/lib/commons-daemon-1.1.0.jar:/usr/local/monitorFEL/monitorFEL.jar com.base.daemon.MonitorDaemon
```

Me brinda el siguiente error

```
Daemon loading...
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.base.daemon.MonitorDaemon
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.load(DaemonLoader.java:148)
Cannot load daemon
java_load failed
Service exit with a return value of 3
```

A continuación el resultado completo del debub

```
+-- DUMPING PARSED COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS --------------
| Detach:          True
| Show Version:    No
| Show Help:       No
| Check Only:      Disabled
| Stop:            False
| Wait:            0
| Run as service:  No
| Install service: No
| Remove service:  No
| JVM Name:        "null"
| Java Home:       "null"
| PID File:        "/var/run/jsvc.pid"
| User Name:       "null"
| Extra Options:   1
|   "-Djava.class.path=/usr/local/monitorFEL/lib/commons-daemon-1.1.0.jar:/usr/local/monitorFEL/monitorFEL.jar"
| Class Invoked:   "com.base.daemon.MonitorDaemon"
| Class Arguments: 0
+-------------------------------------------------------
Home not specified on command line, using environment
Attempting to locate Java Home in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
Attempting to locate VM configuration file /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jvm.cfg
Attempting to locate VM configuration file /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/jvm.cfg
Attempting to locate VM configuration file /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg
Found VM configuration file at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg
Found VM server definition in configuration
Checking library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
Found VM client definition in configuration
Checking library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/client/libjvm.so
Checking library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/client/libjvm.so
Cannot locate library for VM client (skipping)
Found VM zero definition in configuration
Checking library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/zero/libjvm.so
Checking library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/zero/libjvm.so
Cannot locate library for VM zero (skipping)
Found VM dcevm definition in configuration
Checking library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/dcevm/libjvm.so
Checking library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/dcevm/libjvm.so
Cannot locate library for VM dcevm (skipping)
Java Home located in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
+-- DUMPING JAVA HOME STRUCTURE ------------------------
| Java Home:       "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
| Java VM Config.: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg"
| Found JVMs:      1
| JVM Name:        "server"
|                  "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so"
+-------------------------------------------------------
Using default JVM in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
Invoking w/ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64
+-- DUMPING PARSED COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS --------------
| Detach:          True
| Show Version:    No
| Show Help:       No
| Check Only:      Disabled
| Stop:            False
| Wait:            0
| Run as service:  No
| Install service: No
| Remove service:  No
| JVM Name:        "null"
| Java Home:       "null"
| PID File:        "/var/run/jsvc.pid"
| User Name:       "null"
| Extra Options:   1
|   "-Djava.class.path=/usr/local/monitorFEL/lib/commons-daemon-1.1.0.jar:/usr/local/monitorFEL/monitorFEL.jar"
| Class Invoked:   "com.base.daemon.MonitorDaemon"
| Class Arguments: 0
+-------------------------------------------------------
Home not specified on command line, using environment
Attempting to locate Java Home in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
Attempting to locate VM configuration file /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jvm.cfg
Attempting to locate VM configuration file /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/jvm.cfg
Attempting to locate VM configuration file /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg
Found VM configuration file at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg
Found VM server definition in configuration
Checking library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
Found VM client definition in configuration
Checking library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/client/libjvm.so
Checking library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/client/libjvm.so
Cannot locate library for VM client (skipping)
Found VM zero definition in configuration
Checking library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/zero/libjvm.so
Checking library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/zero/libjvm.so
Cannot locate library for VM zero (skipping)
Found VM dcevm definition in configuration
Checking library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/dcevm/libjvm.so
Checking library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/dcevm/libjvm.so
Cannot locate library for VM dcevm (skipping)
Java Home located in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
+-- DUMPING JAVA HOME STRUCTURE ------------------------
| Java Home:       "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
| Java VM Config.: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg"
| Found JVMs:      1
| JVM Name:        "server"
|                  "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so"
+-------------------------------------------------------
Running w/ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64
redirecting stdout to /dev/null and stderr to /dev/null
Switching umask back to 022 from 077
Using default JVM in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
Attemtping to load library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
morris@morris-ThinkPad-E470:/usr/bin$ JVM library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so loaded
JVM library entry point found (0xC5F62F90)
+-- DUMPING JAVA VM CREATION ARGUMENTS -----------------
| Version:                       0x010004
| Ignore Unrecognized Arguments: True
| Extra options:                 1
|   "-Djava.class.path=/usr/local/monitorFEL/lib/commons-daemon-1.1.0.jar:/usr/local/monitorFEL/monitorFEL.jar" (0x00000000)
+-------------------------------------------------------
| Internal options:              4
|   "-Dcommons.daemon.process.id=23091" (0x00000000)
|   "-Dcommons.daemon.process.parent=23090" (0x00000000)
|   "-Dcommons.daemon.version=1.0.15-dev" (0x00000000)
|   "abort" (0x00405af0)
+-------------------------------------------------------
Java VM created successfully
Class org/apache/commons/daemon/support/DaemonLoader found
Native methods registered
java_init done
Daemon loading...
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.base.daemon.MonitorDaemon
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.load(DaemonLoader.java:148)
Cannot load daemon
java_load failed
Service exit with a return value of 3
```

Alguien podría indicarme la razón por la cual jsvc no encuentra la clase?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden